# Use global variable shown issue in sonarqube in javascript nodejs

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

Sonarqube is showing issue "*When a non-existent variable is referenced a ReferenceError is raised*" in Node JS even I mentioned variable as globally in another file.

I declared a variable like `global.variable=TestData`.

I can access this variable in the another files without any issues but when I execute sonar scan I am getting the issue mentioned.

Please advise this how  to solve this.